# \varsigma is not being compiled in beamer with metropolis theme

Tags: beamer, math-mode, equations, compiling

I'm using latex beamer (with metropolis theme) to build my presentation. There, when I tried to use the symbol `\varsigma`, it's not being compiled as like in the document class of "article" where I regularly use this symbol. Instead, it is showing the output similar to the symbol `\sigma`. Any lead would be helpful to quick construct of my presentation. Awaiting!

This is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis}
\usepackage{eulervm}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Table of contents}
\textcolor{red}{$\varsigma$}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805).

Comment: That was my bad. The issue was not with `metropolis` theme, but it was because of the package `eulervm`. Sorry for the inconvenience. I've added the codes and output for your notice.
```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer} \usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis}
\usepackage{eulervm}
\begin{document} \begin{frame}{Table of contents}
\textcolor{red}{$\varsigma$}
\end{frame} \end{document}
```[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3RYRR.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3RYRR.png)

Answer (score 1):

My MWE seems to work:

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Table of contents}
$\varsigma$
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have discovered two things:

1. `eulervm` is not really compatible with the `metropolis` theme
2. `eulervm` doesn't provide a glyph for `\varsigma` and defines it as an alias to `\sigma`

```
%%% line 99 in eulervm.sty
\let\varsigma=\sigma
```